# receive microphone sound without hearing it

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

This captures microphone sound and changes the alpha of 'foo' according to the sound level. However, I hear the microphones input. I want the visuals to work without hearing any sound. How would I do that?

```
m = Microphone.get();

_root.attachAudio(m);
m.setVolume(0); //i can still hear sound. does not mute mic.

onEnterFrame = function () {
foo._alpha = m.activityLevel+33;
};
```

EDIT: **ANSWER / SOLUTION**

series8217's trick with setLoopBack did not work, but that led me to the answer online:

```
m = Microphone.get();
var myAudio:Sound=new Sound(attachAudio(m));
myAudio.setVolume(0);
```

thanks for your time

EDIT: **OTHER SOLUTION**

my trick may interfere with sound. using this, mutes the mic but flash still receives input:

```
m = Microphone.get();
m.setSilenceLevel(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching the loopback mode on the microphone object should do the trick.

```
m.setLoopBack(false);
```

However, if that doesn't do it, perhaps your OS sound settings have monitor or loopback mode turned on. I'd say look into that before trying setLoopback().